# Ios mobile doesn't ask geolocation permission

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use the Google Maps API and get current location.

my page is being served over HTTPS.
I have no problems on Android devices. The browser wants location permission and I can get my location. But ios phone does not want access permission and gives location permission error.

is there anything i can do to ask for access permission for ios phone?

Here is my code

```
function findMyPlace() {
                    if (navigator.geolocation) {
                        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError, { timeout: 20000 });
                    } else {
                         x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
                    }
                }

function showPosition(position) {
            //do something
            }
```

Comment: Make sure that your Location Services on the device are on for Safari. Go to Settings > Privacy > Location Services > Safari Websites and make sure it is set to ON.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation for [getCurrentPosition over at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition)
you can see that `getCurrentPosition()` has an error callback. Apply the error callback and see what type of response you get. I've added a code-sample below.

```
function findMyPlace() {
    if (window.navigator.geolocation) {
        window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( (position) => {
            console.log(position.coords);
        }, (e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
    } else {
        console.log("navigator not supported");
    }
}
findMyPlace();
```